# Why does this query give a different result for the same name?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Let's say I want find a Stack Overflow user by location.

### Note: In my case city location

I found the query, and [here is the link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/9320/find-stack-overflow-users-in-your-city-with-user-links).

In this query we can found user by location.

## Example: I want the user from surat city.

If I write `surat` and run the query it gives the below **result**:

[image]

But when I write the city name `first letter Capital` like **Surat**, see below image.

[image]

Both results are true.

> because the user which have write `first letter Capital` it show in
> `Surat`. and the user which have write `first letter small` it show in
> `surat` detail.

**My question is:**

Is there a query which displays the **combination of these two results** or `ignore Small / Capital` and give the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indicate the collation to use for your `LIKE` statement, as I did in your [forked query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/476139/find-stack-overflow-users-in-your-city-with-user-links?Location=surat)

```
Location like '%##Location##%' collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AI
```

The above collate tells Sql Server to compare the `Location` and the parameter case insensitive and accent insensitive. See the [COLLATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) clause.

Almost all fields in the database are defined as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` which is the reason you have different results when using upper or lower case characters.

In the above query the other result sets show the collation info from the server, databases and that specific column.